# html report in Cucumber

Tags: cucumber, watir-webdriver

I am specify the test case passed or failed based on some conditions.
exp:if $browser.text.include? 'Branch: swfeature_int [ Shortlist ]'
puts "Test Case Passed:Login is successfull"
else
puts "Test case Failed:Login is not successfull"
end
i am getting the Test case Failed:Login is not successfull,but it's shows the green color in html report.But i want it to be shown in red colour i.e it shud be a failed scenario.
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You need a line in your code that validates the expected behavior.

If you are using cucumber, and have the proper rspec gems installed as well (it usually does that for you) then you would use code like this in the step file for the step that matches something like `Then I should see the shortlist` in your feature file

```
browser.text.should include 'Branch: swfeature_int [ Shortlist ]'
```

puts are fine for debugging, but when using an acceptance or unit testing tool, you need to invoke methods (such as `assert` or `.should`) that the framework recognizes as validating expected behavior.  When the condition specified is true, the step passes, when it is false the step fails.

May I STRONGLY suggest you immediately purchase and read ["The Cucumber Book"](http://pragprog.com/book/hwcuc/the-cucumber-book) from pragmatic programmers. It will get you started off using cucumber in the correct way.  you can buy the E version and be reading it a few minutes later.